# WORDPRESS Where to find advanced custom fields selects name in phpmyadmin wp database?

Tags: database, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I can't find in the database that ACF stores the names of the SELECT type fields. The number of elements is there, but there is no corresponding name. Can somebody help me?

I'm looking at the database, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each ACF field is stored as a post in the {{wp prefix}}_posts table, and the public name of the field is in the post_title column, while the slug of the field is in the post_excerpt column.  The post type is acf-field, BTW.

Comment: Ok, it's in wp_posts, not wp_postmeta. I had the wrong idea that it was stored. Thanks!